# Xamarin forms: Windows 10 Universal App prevent screenshot

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, uwp, xamarin.uwp

Hi I am building an app using Xamarin forms PCL project. In this app, I want to prevent users from taking screenshot so for android I tried-

```
this.Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Secure, WindowManagerFlags.Secure);
```

In mainactivity.cs

For windows 10 and 8.1 I found-

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsScreenCaptureEnabled = false;
```

I tried to put it in MainPage.xaml.cs in UWP project. but my app dont start at all after this. Only splash screen is shown.

Where to place this line of code?

```
public sealed partial class MainPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsScreenCaptureEnabled = false;
        LoadApplication(new FISE.App());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you calling somewhere Window.Current.Activate() ? this should be in the App.xaml.cs

Comment: Should be done after setting Window.Current.Content. Doing it in the mainpage sounds as a place where it easily happens before

Comment: I tried    `// Place the frame in the current Window
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
                Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsScreenCaptureEnabled = false;`

Comment: I have set a timer of about 10 second and then I set `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView(‌​).IsScreenCaptureEna‌​bled = false;`

It worked. But due to this all the pages inside my view goes white.